Impatient user upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04 desktop on laptop. There are several issues. Downgrade or wait for a better 24.04?
As an impatient user I've used sudo do-release-upgrade to upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04, fully aware of the risk involved. But it seems 24.04 comes with way more issues than earlier versions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrade+24.04
A few things I noticed (so far) on my Huawei Matebook X after upgrading from 23.10:

screen remained black after upgrade
brightness keys not working anymore
wake up after suspend not (always?) working (or again just a black screen)
Keepass2 doesn't start anymore

Issue #1 was solvable.
Question: what the better path forward to a more functional installation:

downgrade back to 23.10 and wait for a proper 24.04 upgrade
stay on 24.04 and apt-get update + upgrade will solve these and
maybe some additional  problems (in a few weeks)
...


You borked (not working properly, broken) your system by not following the recommended instructions to wait until the first point release is available before upgrading. Instead of fixing your system apt update could apt upgrade could break it even more because of accumulated package management errors.
I recommend option 3. ... back up all your personal data and fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. Try running Ubuntu 24.04 as a live session from the USB Ubuntu installer before installing Ubuntu 24.04 to check if the brightness keys and suspend work and Keepass2 starts properly.
